# Android - Background color with different color and angles

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml, android-shape

I'm trying to figure out how to create this background in xml,
couldn't find anything that helped me.

[image: background]

Ignore the circle image of the kid and the text of course, I am talking about the background itself, is there a way to create something like that in xml?

Thanks in advance for any help.
cheers!

Comment: You may be able to do it using a LayerList, but using shape does not appear to support triangle shapes :/

Comment: Cannot be done with just the xml . you will have to use rotate() method in the java class. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590176/5060269) may help

Comment: You can manage in single custom view. In custom view, draw this background in canvas.

Comment: try to user https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5659 library

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you moved on, but you can do this using [Vector Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html).

The following is not accurate (the line is not completely straight), but should give you a good start:

New XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:name="dark_triangle"
        android:fillColor="@color/blue"
        android:pathData="M 0,100 L 0,80 60,70 100,80 100,100 z" />

    <path
        android:name="light_triangle"
        android:fillColor="@color/color_light_blue"
        android:pathData="M 60,70 L 100,65 100,80 z" />

</vector>
```

In your layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/test"
    />
```

You might need to add this to your layout as well:

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Notes:

- Some more resources if someone will be interested: [1](https://dev.to/brightdevs/creating-simple-vector-drawables-in-android-studio-bbm) [2](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/understanding-vectordrawable-pathdata-commands-in-android-d56a6054610e).
- [There's a preview for Vector Drawables in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685042/4759619).
- Vector Drawables has been introduced in API 21, but should be supported in [older APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795933/4759619).