# How to see a preview of custom vector asset (added by SVG format) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know i can use my own svg as icons by browsing them from the asset studio but it just show the name not the exact icon of the svg, i can't know just by name what that icon is look like , **so can i view them while adding them to project like they are showing in below image?**

I have many icon on my computer can i add them to that list , so that i can see them visually when i want to add a new vector asset. 
I tend to think that it can be done because then icons which android asset studio  is shows must be stored in a directory from where it pulls when when i open asset stdio , if i can add my svg to that directory then android studio may may also pull them too with default clip arts and they may also show up in asset studio, does anyone know what that directory is , or any other way of doing this.

**Note android studio does not give such option via UI**

[image: Vector asset studio]

Comment: You may go through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091618/is-there-a-way-to-preview-a-vector-drawable) which might have some clues

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new vector asset (assuming you've added it in the drawable directory), it gets added in the drawable directory. 
It is generally saved by the name `ic_thatSVGname`. So it gets the prefix IC. So please browse in the drawable directory and you will find your vector asset. 
Then double click on it so that it opens and you can see the preview on right side of the screen. It it doesn't, just click the PREVIEW button which also reside on the right side of the Android Studio.
So that means just search for that in drawable directory. And while adding new vector assets, right click on the DRAWABLE DIRECTORY only so that it gets into that directory else it might end up outside it.

Comment: i think i couldn't explain the question , "I want to see the  preview before adding the vector to the project like i can see the preview of cliparts the android studio provides, i have hundreds of svg in a folder i can't try adding all to see if that is what i wanted

Comment: You can't simply add those in the Android Studio'es vector collection. You have to find them in drawable folder. You can check their previ2 by opening them.

Comment: how to add , so that i can see the preview as a list before adding to my project?

Comment: i want to see them before adding to project as the clip arts are showing in the image in question, note that android studio doesn't provide such option , i wonder if i can browse the directories of android studio itself and add my svg to same folder where these clip arts are located

Comment: I don't think there's any alternative to that. All you can do is name them in a well known order so that you can find them easily in the directory.

Comment: yes but i think if i can put my vectors in same folder where the cliparts are placed then android studio may pull my vectors too with the cliparts , but i don't  where these cliparts are saved, i got hundreds of svgs with a course i can't remember all names